# a $p$-Laplacian Dirichlet-problem with finite elements

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I would like to solve the $p$-Laplace dirichlet problem
\begin{align*}
 -\Delta_p u & = 1 \quad\text{in } \Omega:=[0,1]^2 \\
u & = 0 \quad\text{on }\partial\Omega
\end{align*}
for some $p>1$ with linear finite elements.

This can be done using a Newton method where we iterate over the solution $u^k$  and assemble the stiffness matrix $K = (k_{ij})$ where
$$k_{ij} = \int |\nabla u^k|^{p-2}\nabla\varphi_j^T\nabla\varphi_i dx + (p-2)\int |\nabla u^k|^{p-4}(\nabla (u^k)^T\nabla\varphi_j)(\nabla (u^k)^T\nabla\varphi_i)dx$$
in each iteration.

Now my problem is that I do not know how to compute $\nabla u^k$. In each step I know $u^k$, i.e. a vector with the value of $u^k$ at each node, but I don't know how to compute the gradient from this.

Does anyone know any references for this or has experience in how to program this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u^k=\sum_{i=1}^NU^k_i\varphi_i$, where $N$ is the number of degrees of freedom, and $\varphi_i,\,\,\,i=1,\ldots,N$ are the basis functions, then $\nabla u^k=\sum_{i=1}^NU^k_i\nabla\varphi_i$.